# Stocks given by company vest if I quit?

Tags: stocks

My company has given me some stock that vests a certain amount every year.  When I log in to the broker's website I can see the projected amount I can take out in 1 year, 2 years, and so on.  If I leave my job for some reason, but don't take the money from the account, does it still vest, or does the account balance stop going up at the time I leave?

I know this is a vague question that might be situation / company dependent.  I'm interested in how things generally work.

Comment: I think it's too company dependent to have a good answer.  Your company stock might vest immediately, it might vest 20% per year for 5 years, it might vest 100% in 5 years and 0% before that.  A lot of this depends on what _kind_ of company you are in: if you're in a small startup, odds are it's the latter (vesting later only) as an incentive not to quit.  If you're working for an established company, it might vest on a 20% per year (or even 100% immediately) basis.

Comment: Either way, you need to find the agreement in your benefits paperwork.  Your HR department should be able to provide it for you (probably, by law must provide it for you) if you don't have access on your corporate intranet/etc.

Comment: @Joe while I agree the exact vesting mechanics while you're employed somewhere are "too company-dependent to have a good answer," I'd be astounded if there is anywhere in the world where your stock keeps vesting *after you leave*, which is what the question is asking.

Comment: The whole point of the vesting schedule is to give you an incentive to remain an employee of the company.

Comment: Not only do you stop vesting, but you may have a limited time after leaving to exercise your already vested options.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were probably not given stock, but stock options.  Those options have a strike price and you can do some more research on them if needed.  Lets assume that you were given 5K shares at a strike of 20, and they vest 20% per year.  Assume the same thing in your second year and you are going to leave in year three.

You would have 2K shares from your year 1 grant, and 1K shares from your year 2 grant, so 2K total.

If you leave no more shares would be vested.

If you leave you have one of two options:

1. Cash in the options and take the difference between the strike and current price.  So if the current stock price was $25, you could cash out 5*3K = $15K.  Note, however, this is not possible if the company is still private.
2. Purchase any portion of the options.  So in this case you could purchase all of the shares for 60K.  Note however, this money could be lost in full.

To complicate matters subsequent grants may have different strike prices, so perhaps year two grant is at $22 per share.  However, in pre-public companies that is not likely the case.

For a bit of history, I worked at a pre-ipo company and we were all going to get rich.  I was given generous grants, but decided to leave.  I really wanted to buy my options but simply didn't have the money.  Shortly after I left the company folded, so the money would have been thrown away anyway.  When a company is private the motivate their employees with tales of riches, but they are not required to disclose financial data.  This company did a very good job of convincing employees that all was fine, when it wasn't.

Also I received options in a publicly traded company.  Myself and other employees received options that were "underwater" or worth far less than the strike price.  You could let them expire so one did not owe money, but they were worthless.

Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: Much more thorough than my answer, +1.

Comment: @Pete B. - Thanks for the great answer.  If you don't mind, I have one more question about this - is there a disadvantage to taking out the money each year, as the stock vests (not taking into account increase in the price of the stock)?

Comment: Ahhh there is the rub....I had a buddy that cashed em out as soon as he could, and another who was a holder.  In that case the buddy was right.  The company was Symantec, whose stock price has been flat for the last 15 years (when I worked there).  For some companies, holding would have been a better option.

Comment: @Joe I would have up voted your answer for its elegance.

Comment: @PeteB. - You've helped me a lot, thank you very much.

Comment: Well then, I suppose I can undelete it... but I like the detail more (and particularly the very relevant point about stock options).

Answer (score 6):

Vesting typically stops after you quit.

So, if your plan vests 20% per year for 5 years, and you received a one-time stock grant as part of this plan (i.e., ignoring the fact that these often involve new grants each year that vest separately), and you were hired in 2014 and leave at the end of 2016, then you vested 20% in 2015 and 20% in 2016, so would have 40% of the stock vested when you quit, and would never have more than that.